# Limit of morphism of sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory

I hope someone can help me with the following:

Say I am given two sheaves $F,G$ on a topological space $X$. 
How can i proof the Isomorphism of
$Hom(F,G) \cong \varprojlim Hom(F\mid_U, G\mid_U)$ 
And how does this look like.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Is the limit taken for every open set $U$ ? In that case, it follows simply from the fact that $X$ is a terminal object in $Open(X)$.

Comment: Thats right, its taken over every open subset. could you please right that i a little more formal way, that would be awesome

Comment: @E.J.K. : this is already very formal. For a directed limit, if you have a terminal object in the indexing set (i.e a $j_0$ such that $ j_0 \leq j, \forall j \in J$) then $\lim_{j \in J} F_j = F_{j_0}$.